# Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection

Tags: jsp, struts, jsp-tags, struts-config

hello guy's i am new in struts while running a program in struss i got an error like this....

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:531)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:901)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:830)
    org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspService(insert_jsp.java:83)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:798)
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:506)
    org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f0(insert_jsp.java:136)
    org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fhtml_005f0(insert_jsp.java:106)
    org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspService(insert_jsp.java:73)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

mycode are like this......

web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

struts-config.xml

```
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="insertForm" type="com.cac.struts.InsertForm">
    </form-beans>
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/insert" type="com.cac.struts.InsertAction" name="insertForm">
            <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp">
            <forward name="failure" path="/failure.jsp">
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

hello guy's i am new in struts while running a program in struss i got an error like this....

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:531)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

root cause

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:901)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:830)
    org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspService(insert_jsp.java:83)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

root cause

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find ActionMappings or ActionFormBeans collection
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:798)
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:506)
    org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f0(insert_jsp.java:136)
    org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fhtml_005f0(insert_jsp.java:106)
    org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspService(insert_jsp.java:73)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:332)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

mycode are like this......

### InsertModel.java

```
package com.cac.struts;
import java.sql.*;
public class InsertModel
{
    public boolean insert(String name,String branch,int regd)
    {
        boolean b=false;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mohit","system","rock");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into emp values(?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1,name);
            ps.setString(2,branch);
            ps.setInt(3,regd);
            int k=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(k>0)
                b=true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

### InsertForm.java

```
package com.cac.struts;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
public class InsertForm extends ActionForm
{
    private int regd;
    private String name;
    private String branch;
    public void setRegd(int r)
    {
        regd=r;
    }
    public int getRegd()
    {
        return regd;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setBranch(String branch)
    {
        this.branch=branch;
    }
    public String getBranch()
    {
        return branch;
    }
}
```

### InsertAction.java

```
package com.cac.struts;
import org.apache.struts.action.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class InsertAction extends Action
{
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping am,ActionForm af,HttpServletRequest hreq,HttpServletResponse hres) throws Exception
    {
        String key="failure";
        InsertForm iif=(InsertForm)af;
        int regd=iif.getRegd();
        String name=iif.getName();
        String branch=iif.getBranch();
        InsertModel im=new InsertModel();
        boolean b=im.insert(name,branch,regd);
        if(b)
        {
            key="success";
        }
        ActionForward af1=am.findForward(key);
        return af1;
    }
}
```

### web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### struts-config.html

```
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="insertForm" type="com.cac.struts.InsertForm">
    </form-beans>
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/insert" type="com.cac.struts.InsertAction" name="insertForm">
            <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp">
            <forward name="failure" path="/failure.jsp">
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

### insert.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<html:html>
    <body bgcolor="yellow">
    <center>
        <h1>Student Application</h1>
        <html:form action="insert" method="post">
            regd<html:text property="regd"/><br><br>
            name<html:text property="name"/><br><br>
            branch<html:text property="branch"/><br><br>
        <html:submit>insert</html:submit>
        </html:form>
    </center>
    </body>
</html:html>
```

in addition i am also using all the jar files in lib and a struts-html.tld. Please...Please help me...!!

Answer (score 1):

Adding commons-beanutils jar to your classpath may resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you did not add input in action mapping ..in struts-config.xml      input="/insert.jsp"

try this

```
< action path="/insert" type="com.cac.struts.InsertAction" 
        name="insertForm" scope="request" validate="false" input="/insert.jsp">
```

ok

Answer (score 0):

Probably you made entries in web.xml first and later you added the required jars especially commons-beanutils.jar.  Simply delete the contents of web.xml and rewrite them.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have included following jars in your project

1. antlr-2.7.6.jar
2. commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
3. commons-chain-1.2.jar
4. commons-collections-3.1.jar
5. commons-digester-2.0.jar
6. commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
7. commons-io-2.0.1.jar
8. commons-lang-2.5.jar
9. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
10. commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
11. commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
12. dom4j-1.6.1.jar
13. hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
14. hibernate3.jar
15. javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
16. jstl-api-1.2.jar
17. jstl-impl-1.2.jar
18. jta-1.1.jar
19. mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar
20. ognl-3.0.1.jar
21. slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
22. slf4j-log4j12-1.6.2.jar
23. spring-beans-2.5.6.jar
24. spring-context-2.5.6.jar
25. spring-core-2.5.6.jar
26. spring-test-2.5.6.jar
27. spring-web-2.5.6.jar
28. struts2-core-2.2.3.1.jar
29. xwork-core-2.2.3.1.jar

If still face problem please download following sample project from google code

http://struts-workspace-setup.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Answer (score 0):

You missed mapping in `web.xml`, it should be like this:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Also rename `struts-config.html` to `struts-config.xml`.

Comment: You missed `</init-param>` closing tag, so I had closed it for you.